# Replacing values in a pandas Series with another value using regex

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a pandas Series as showed below:

```
Type

Bayer
Seller_agency
holding Advertiser
LLC Agency
```

and I want to replace all series value which contains '[Aa]gency to 'Agency' otherwise change it to 'Advertiser'.

I tried

```
data['Type'] = data['Type'].replace(to_replace='\[aA]gency.', value = 'Agency', regex = True)
```

which changed the only substring but not the whole string.

Comment: `df['Type'].str.replace('.*([aA]gency).*|.+', lambda x: x.group(1).title() if x.group(1) else 'Advertiser')`

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it did not work for me as I wanted.

Comment: @here thank you all. with your help and additional research, I satisfy my execution.